# How to punctuate the phrase "and more than that"?

Tags: punctuation

How should I punctuate the following sentence? I think I should use comma before and after "and more than that".

> Being accepted in your job position helps me to achieve my goals more effectively, and more than that, helps your company to benefit from a great engineer.

Comment: The commas are correct there. Curious: do you mean to say this before or after taking the job?

Comment: @gotube I want to write it in my personal statement (before taking the job). Do you discourage me from saying so?

Comment: @gotube This is a research position in neuroscience. My paragraph: "I do not want to work in you laboratory only because I think I am good at neuroscience and have found it a good way to make a living, but rather I seek knowledge about the brain in order to satisfy my inner thirst about the nature of my cognitive abilities. Even if I am not accepted in any neuroscience positions, I will continue my research until the end of my life, but being accepted in your job position helps me to achieve my goals more effectively, and more than that, helps your company to benefit from a great engineer."

Comment: In that case, since you haven't been accepted yet, you should shift your sentence to the future with "will": "*Being accepted in your job position **will help** me to achieve my goals more effectively, and more than that, **will help** your company to benefit from a great engineer.*" GOOD LUCK TO YOU!!!!